# Facebook Apps - Add Platform - Website icon is grayed out and won't let me click it

Tags: facebook, ning

None of the answers to related issues have helped me.

I am trying to create a Facebook login for my Ning site. When I Add Platform under settings, it is only the 'Website' icon that is unclickable.

I followed the Ning instructions for enabling this to the letter, they are here:
http://www.ning.com/ning3help/enable-social-sign-in-with-facebook/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post a screenshot? and perhaps the affected app id?

Comment: Any chance you already have a website integration configured? (or are you in the Games category and already have a canvas / 'website on facebook' platform configured?)

Comment: thanks for the help. i dont already have website configured and my category is not games. cant post images apparently. app id is 231397657054451

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too:[image]

In my case it was because the Website section was already added:[image]